# Resize text area of input box in HTML

Tags: html, textbox, resize

I'm new to HTML and i'm trying to resize my input box. This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Text Summarizer </h1>
<div class="login">
<h1>Insert the text that you want to summarize in the box below</h1>

  <form action="{{url_for('summary')}}"method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="type here" required="required"> 
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit",value="summary">
  </form> 
  <br>
  <br>
  {{data}}
  </div>
```

Here's what i have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Text Summarizer </h1>
<div class="login">
<h1>Insert the text that you want to summarize in the box below</h1>

  <form action="{{url_for('summary')}}"method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="type here" required="required"> 
    <br><br>
   <textarea rows= "4" cols="50">
   </textarea>
   <br><br>
    <input type="submit",value="summary">
  </form> 
  <br>
  <br>
  {{data}}
  </div>
```

I'm now getting a second box next to my original textbox.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you want an increased input tag, try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Text Summarizer </h1>
<div class="login">
<h1>Insert the text that you want to summarize in the box below</h1>

  <form action="{{url_for('summary')}}"method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="type here" required="required" style="width:35%; height:100px;"> 
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="summary">
  </form> 
  <br>
  <br>
  {{data}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be a big text field with the "type here" placeholder, do the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Text Summarizer </h1>
<div class="login">
<h1>Insert the text that you want to summarize in the box below</h1>

  <form action="{{url_for('summary')}}"method="post">
   <textarea rows= "4" cols="50" type="text" name="input" placeholder="type here" required="required">
   </textarea>
   <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="summary">
  </form> 
  <br>
  <br>
  {{data}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you very much. It seems that when the users don't type an input the program breaks. Is there a way to fix that?